# What small adjustments can I make to these MySQL queries to get the results I need?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got a MySQL database with tables 'people', 'questions', and 'answers'. I'm trying to get some easily readable results.
I have this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) as Name, 
people.emailAddress,
(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'apple' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE ''
END) as Apple,
(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'orange' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE ''
END) as Orange,
(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'banana' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE ''
END) as Banana
From answers
Join questions ON answers.fruitID = questions.fruitID 
JOIN people ON questions.person = people.person 
WHERE questions.questionnaire = '24' 
ORDER BY people.person
```

Which produces this result:

```
    +------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
    |       Name       |    emailAddress    | Apple | Orange | Banana |
    +------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
    | Harry Potter     | hpotter@gmail.com  | YES   |        |        |
    | Harry Potter     | hpotter@gmail.com  | YES   |        |        |
    | Harry Potter     | hpotter@gmail.com  | YES   |        |        |
    | Ron Weasley      | rweasley@gmail.com | YES   |        |        |
    | Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | YES   | YES    |        |
    | Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | YES   |        |        |
    | Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | YES   |        |        |
    | Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | YES   | YES    |        |
    | Remus Lupin      | rlupin@gmail.com   | YES   |        |        |
    | Viktor Krum      | vkrum@gmail.com    | YES   |        |        |
    | Molly Weasley    | mweasley@gmail.com | YES   | YES    |        |
    | Oliver Wood      | owood@gmail.com    | YES   |        |        |
    | Oliver Wood      | owood@gmail.com    |       |        | YES    |
    +------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

And that's great. It has all the info I need, but, it would be ideal if there was just one row per person and all the fruits they chose (even if they answered multiple times) was indicated on that one line. I just can't figure out how to get the group by to do what I want. Like this:

```
+------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
|       Name       |    emailAddress    | Apple | Orange | Banana |
+------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
| Harry Potter     | hpotter@gmail.com  | YES   |        |        |
| Ron Weasley      | rweasley@gmail.com | YES   |        |        |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | YES   | YES    |        |
| Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | YES   | YES    |        |
| Remus Lupin      | rlupin@gmail.com   | YES   |        |        |
| Viktor Krum      | vkrum@gmail.com    | YES   |        |        |
| Molly Weasley    | mweasley@gmail.com | YES   | YES    |        |
| Oliver Wood      | owood@gmail.com    | YES   |        | YES    |
+------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

So the desired result above would ignore multiple answers of the same fruit for people. But, there are situations where I'd want to know if someone answered with the same fruit multiple times. So, I've also got this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) as Name, 
people.emailAddress,
SUM(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'apple' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) as 'AppleCount',
SUM(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'orange' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) as 'OrangeCount',
SUM(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'banana' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) as 'BananaCount'
From answers
Join questions ON answers.fruitID = questions.fruitID 
JOIN people ON questions.person = people.person
WHERE questions.questionnaire = '24'
GROUP BY people.person 
ORDER BY people.person
```

Which produces something like this:

```
+------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+
|       Name       |    emailAddress    |  Apple  | Orange  | Banana |
+------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+
| Harry Potter     | hpotter@gmail.com  | 3       | 0       | 0      |
| Ron Weasley      | rweasley@gmail.com | 1       | 0       | 0      |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | 3       | 1       | 0      |
| Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | 1       | 1       | 0      |
| Remus Lupin      | rlupin@gmail.com   | 1       | 0       | 0      |
| Viktor Krum      | vkrum@gmail.com    | 1       | 0       | 0      |
| Molly Weasley    | mweasley@gmail.com | 1       | 1       | 0      |
| Oliver Wood      | owood@gmail.com    | 1       | 0       | 1      |
+------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

And this is also great but could be better with a couple improvements. First (the real problem) is that when a person has no answers yet but they do exist in questions table (because I've sent the questionnaire to them), they don't show up at all with the above query. I'd like to have them listed in the results, they just won't have any fruits chosen. Second, I'd like the "0"s to just be blank. So it would look like this instead:

```
+------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+
|       Name       |    emailAddress    |  Apple  | Orange  | Banana |
+------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+
| Harry Potter     | hpotter@gmail.com  | 3       |         |        |
| Ron Weasley      | rweasley@gmail.com | 1       |         |        |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | 3       | 1       |        |
| Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | 1       | 1       |        |
| Remus Lupin      | rlupin@gmail.com   | 1       |         |        |
| Viktor Krum      | vkrum@gmail.com    | 1       |         |        |
| Molly Weasley    | mweasley@gmail.com | 1       | 1       |        |
| Oliver Wood      | owood@gmail.com    | 1       |         | 1      |
| Argus Filch      | afilch@gmail.com   |         |         |        |
+------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Any ideas on how I can get these two desired results?

Edit: Working on sample data...

Comment: Change join to left join

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data for all tables involved.

Comment: I have voted to close as unclear because you showed us no data, causing everyone to speculate.

Comment: I'm working on sample data and I told you that. I appreciate the help and I understand that it isn't clear for you after you mentioned it. I should have had sample data to begin with. It's just taking a bit because these questions are sensitive and specific so I'm trying to make everything (including people) generic. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think a pivot query can give the output you want.  In the query below I `GROUP BY` the concatenated name and the email address.  The key point here is that we take the `MAX` of something similar to the `CASE` expressions you were using in your original query.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) AS Name,
    people.emailAddress,
    MAX(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'apple'  THEN 'YES' END) AS Apple,
    MAX(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'orange' THEN 'YES' END) AS Orange,
    MAX(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'banana' THEN 'YES' END) AS Banana
FROM answers
LEFT JOIN questions
    ON answers.fruitID = questions.fruitID 
LEFT JOIN people
    ON questions.person = people.person AND
       questions.questionnaire = '24' 
GROUP BY
    CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName),   -- not ANSI compliant, but should
    people.emailAddress                               -- work with MySQL
ORDER BY Name
```

Note that I don't know why you are joining the `answers` table.  If you had included some sample data, maybe this would be obvious.

If you wanted to instead get counts for each of the fruits, then you could use the following `SELECT` with the remainder of the query the same:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) AS Name,
    people.emailAddress,
    SUM(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'apple'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Apple,
    SUM(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'orange' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Orange,
    SUM(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'banana' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Banana
```

Comment: Your first solution fixed the issue I was having with multiple rows per person, thanks! However, neither of your solutions are returning a row for a person that has no records in the answers table but exists in the questions table (because I sent them a questionnaire that they haven't answered yet). Basically, your second solution produces the exact same result as my second solution. I'll try to edit my question with some sample data if that will help.

Comment: @JustaSecUser I moved the `WHERE` condition to the `ON` clause.  Please try my first query again, thanks.

Comment: That edit seems to have maybe made some progress. Now I'm getting a NULL and NULL for the name and email address of the person that has no answers but I'm also getting a "YES" for all the fruits for that NULL person. I'm still trying to get readable format sample tables edited into my question. I know that it's difficult to guess in your position.

Comment: What do you want to show instead of `NULL`?  I'm afraid I can't help you further without seeing your data.

Comment: I'd want it to show the person's name and email address. With this solution, someone who hasn't answered yet looks like this:
Name/Email/Apple/Orange/Banana ->
NULL/NULL/YES/YES/YES

It should look like this:
Name/Email/Apple/Orange/Banana ->
Argus Filch/afilch@gmail.com/ / /

Edit: grrrr, formatting in comments doesn't work at all...

Comment: You asked a bad, unclear, question with no sample data, which caused a lot of people to waste their time trying to help you.

Comment: It wasn't a waste of time. I was able to get some good queries that got me going in the right direction. It has been very helpful to me. Your first solution is mostly what I need (and frankly, will work - it's just not 100% ideal because it doesn't show people who haven't answered yet). I will be able to post sample data today and will comment here again when I do in case you want to help further. If you don't, I understand. I very much appreciate your help so far.

Comment: @JustaSecUser Show us data and we can give you a more exact answer.

Comment: I know it's been a few days (took a while to get the time to put everything together) but I created a new question with sample data. I don't expect your help, but I wanted to fulfill what I said I'd do and let you know. The question is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380775/slight-tweaks-to-mysql-queries-to-get-desired-results

Comment: Your new question is too long IMO.

Comment: LOL, I guess I can't win. It's pretty much the exact length of this question just with the added sample data that was requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) as Name, 
people.emailAddress,
sum((CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'apple' THEN 1
    ELSE  NULL
END) ) as Apple,
sum((CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'orange' THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
END)) as Orange,
sum((CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'banana' THEN 1
    ELSE NULL 
END)) as Banana
From people
LEFT JOIN ON questions questions.person = people.person 
LEFT Join answers  ON answers.fruitID = questions.fruitID 
WHERE questions.questionnaire = '24' 
GROUP BY CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName), people.emailAddress
ORDER BY name, people.emailAddress
```

Comment: it will have multiple record without summing up. if we put it like this @scaisEdge

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I've tried this and I'm looking into why it's not working. All I get returned is a single row (1 person) with all the counts for all the answers from all the people added up together. Trying to figure out why that is happening...

Comment: @JustaSecUser   if you have just a row check for group by  .. i have update the answer  with an explicit group by  .. anyway

Comment: Yep, the group by did the trick and I now see most of the people. Problem is, I'm still not seeing people that have no records in the answers yet. I've sent them the questionnaire so they have records in the questions table, but nothing in the answers table yet. I'd like them to show up in the results query with their name and email address, just with nothing under the fruits obviously. This may be hard to understand because I don't have sample table data in my question so I'm working on getting that added in there.

Comment: Ok  .. this because you use use answer  as main table and not people .. answer  updated  changing main table  ..  .this way you should obtain all the people also if have not answer

Comment: This is very close. As with one of the other answers, I'm now getting people in the results and have no answers yet BUT, I'm getting "1" for everything that should be "0" or blank. For example, the people who haven't answered the questionnaire yet are showing 1 for apple, 1 for orange, and 1 for banana. The other counts are correct (like when a person has 5 "apple" answers for example)

Answer (score 0):

You should use left join instead of join to get Argus which is not have any answer. And put sub query to make the 0 blank because sum result never be blank.

```
SELECT Name, CASE WHEN AppleCount = 0 THEN '' ELSE AppleCount END, 
CASE WHEN OrangeCount= 0 THEN '' ELSE OrangeCount END,
CASE WHEN BananaCount= 0 THEN '' ELSE BananaCount END FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) as Name, 
  people.emailAddress,
  SUM(CASE questions.fruit 
     WHEN 'apple' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
  END) as 'AppleCount',
  SUM(CASE questions.fruit 
     WHEN 'orange' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
  END) as 'OrangeCount',
  SUM(CASE questions.fruit 
   WHEN 'banana' THEN 1
   ELSE 0
  END) as 'BananaCount'
  From people 
  LEFT JOIN ON answers questions.person = people.person
  LEFT JOIN questions ON answers.fruitID = campaign.fruitID 
  WHERE questions.questionnaire = '24'
  GROUP BY people.person 
  ORDER BY people.person) TableA
```

Oops my bad since you want display by people the people should be on top instead on answers table.

Comment: This is close. I'm now getting people in the results and have no answers yet BUT, I'm getting "1" for everything that should be "0" or blank. For example, the people who haven't answered the questionnaire yet are showing 1 for apple, 1 for orange, and 1 for banana. The other counts are correct (like when a person has 5 "apple" answers for example)

Comment: by right it should be 0 or blank because your 'questions.fruit' should be null. Try to put 'AND' condition to make it like CASE WHEN questions.fruit is not null and questions.fruit = 'apple' then 1 else 0